# Angular validation on input button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a fieldset that requires the user to enter some data like name, emai land phone number like this:

```
        <h2 class="fs-title">Personal data</h2>
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="textbox" ng-model="firstName"required/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="textbox" ng-model="lastName" required/>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="textbox" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" required>
        <input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Phone number" id="contact" ng-model="phoneNumber" required/>
        <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next"/>
```

The class `next` has a function associated to it:

```
var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
var left, opacity, scale; //fieldset properties which we will animate
var animating; //flag to prevent quick multi-click glitches


$(".next").click(function(){
    if(animating) return false;
    animating = true;

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();

    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
            //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
            //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
            scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
            //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
            left = (now * 50)+"%";
            //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
            opacity = 1 - now;
            current_fs.css({
                'transform': 'scale('+scale+')',
                'position': 'absolute'
            });
            next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function(){
            current_fs.hide();
            animating = false;
        },
        //this comes from the custom easing plugin
        // easing: 'easeInOutBack'
        linear: 'easeInOutBack'
    });
});
```

In its current state, you can click Next even if the form is not properly completed, even if it's full empty and I don't want that. I want when I click next, to also check if the inputs are properly filled and if not, under each field, a message/warning ot be displayed about what the problem is (ie. on email, it has to contain a @)

I tried using the btn btn-primary classes from bootstrap but if I use them (they do validation as I want) I can't use my next class anymore. Any ideas how to make it work?
I tried Angular directives, like ng-disable on condition that those fields are empty but for some reason, if I fill the fields, the button still doesn't work so how can I use btn btn-primary and still have my next class work?

Answer (score 0):

Use form api:

```
<form ng-submit="saveForm(MyForm.$valid)" name="MyForm">
   <input ng-model="myField" required>
   <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

and somewhere in controller:

```
function saveForm(isValid){
   if(!isValid) showErrors();
   save();
}
```

Comment: I can't use this because I already have a big form that's split in 3, that's why I have the next button who only passes me to the next step, I just want it to pass me on condition.

Comment: Anyway, you should avoid binding click via jquery and trying to use ng-click; Like so : ng-click="MyForm.$valid && handleNextClick()"